# How do you write a fixed len feature to tfrecord

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I'm struggling with the basics of writing a tensorflow tfrecord file. I'm writing a simple example with an ndarray in python, but for some reason when I read it it's required to be variable-length and reads it as a SparseTensor.

Here's the example

```
def serialize_tf_record(features, targets):
    record = {
        'shape': tf.train.Int64List(value=features.shape),
        'features': tf.train.FloatList(value=features.flatten()),
        'targets': tf.train.Int64List(value=targets),
    }

    return build_tf_example(record)

def deserialize_tf_record(record):
    tfrecord_format = {
        'shape': tf.io.VarLenFeature(tf.int64),
        'features': tf.io.VarLenFeature(tf.float32),
        'targets': tf.io.VarLenFeature(tf.int64),
    }

    features_tensor = tf.io.parse_single_example(record, tfrecord_format)
    return features_tensor
```

Can anybody explain to me why this writes a variable-length record? It is fixed in code, but I can't seem to write it in a way tensorflow knows its fixed. The tensorflow documentation is pretty horrific here. Can anybody clarify the API for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should provide more contextual code, like your `build_tf_example` function and examples of your features and targets.

Here is an example which return Dense Tensors:

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

def build_tf_example(record):
    return tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature=record)).SerializeToString()

def serialize_tf_record(features, targets):
    record = {
        'shape': tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=features.shape)),
        'features': tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=features.flatten())),
        'targets': tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=targets)),
    }

    return build_tf_example(record)

def deserialize_tf_record(record):
    tfrecord_format = {
        'shape': tf.io.FixedLenSequenceFeature((), dtype=tf.int64, allow_missing=True),
        'features': tf.io.FixedLenSequenceFeature((), dtype=tf.float32, allow_missing=True),
        'targets': tf.io.FixedLenSequenceFeature((), dtype=tf.int64, allow_missing=True),
    }

    features_tensor = tf.io.parse_single_example(record, tfrecord_format)
    return features_tensor

def main():
    features = np.zeros((3, 5, 7))
    targets = np.ones((4,), dtype=int)
    tf.print(deserialize_tf_record(serialize_tf_record(features, targets)))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

- I converted `record` to a dictionary of Features (to easily serialize it)
- From what I understood, each of your feature can be an array (opposed to a scalar value), hence you can parse it using `FixedLenSequenceFeature` input feature to build a dense tensor instead of a sparse one.